# Receipts for FL donors

Tags: civicontribute, message-templates, system-workflow-messages

The state of Florida, USA requires a special statement on contribution acknowledgements & receipts. I am trying to edit the online and offline workflow template so that it will include that statement if the contact.state_province is FL. Can someone please help me get the code dialed in?

Thanks in advance

```
{if $contact.state_province eq 'FL'}
 <p>A COPY OF THE OFFICIAL REGISTRATION AND FINANCIAL INFORMATION MAY BE OBTAINED FROM THE DIVISION OF CONSUMER SERVICES BY CALLING TOLL-FREE (800-435-7352) WITHIN THE STATE. REGISTRATION DOES NOT IMPLY ENDORSEMENT, APPROVAL, OR RECOMMENDATION BY THE STATE.</p>
{/if}
```

I tried it without the $ first. So... {if contact.state_province eq 'FL'}

I tried the code below but it put it on all receipts

```
 {assign var="florida" value="{contact.state_province eq 'FL'}{if $florida}<p>A COPY OF THE OFFICIAL REGISTRATION AND FINANCIAL INFORMATION MAY BE OBTAINED FROM THE DIVISION OF CONSUMER SERVICES BY CALLING TOLL-FREE (800-435-7352) WITHIN THE STATE OF FLORIDA. REGISTRATION DOES NOT IMPLY ENDORSEMENT, APPROVAL, OR RECOMMENDATION BY THE STATE OF FLORIDA.</p>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state token is a token and not a smarty variable, so it has to just be on its own, and you can't use it in the middle of a smarty `if` statement. You have to `capture` it first into a smarty variable:

```
{capture assign=stateProv}{contact.state_province}{/capture}
{if $stateProv eq 'FL'}
 <p>A COPY OF THE OFFICIAL REGISTRATION AND FINANCIAL INFORMATION MAY BE OBTAINED FROM THE DIVISION OF CONSUMER SERVICES BY CALLING TOLL-FREE (800-435-7352) WITHIN THE STATE. REGISTRATION DOES NOT IMPLY ENDORSEMENT, APPROVAL, OR RECOMMENDATION BY THE STATE.</p>
{/if}
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!